# Cron command in server to Zip a folder and exclude other?

Tags: cron, command

I created a cron task in the hosting of my website. I use this command:

```
 zip -r public_html.zip public_html -x *public_html/cache/smarty*
```

As you can see I'm trying to zip the **public_html** excluding the folder: **public_html/cache/smarty**

The zip is created but I can not get to exclude the folder.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

`zip -r public_html.zip public_html -x *cache/smarty/*`

Comment: @canelones yeah, just don't need to include that parent directory :)